# Please Explain why the Program output is 0 (programming in c)

Tags: c, variables, default-value

Code:
#include <stdio.h>

```
int main()
{
    int x;

    printf("%d\n",x);
    if(x>10)
      x-=10;
    else if(x>=0)
      x+=00;
    else if(x)
      x+=10;
    else
      x-=10;
      printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Why initial value of x is zero? what is the default value of int, float, double, char type data in c. In this program x is assigned by default value or garbage value.

Comment: Undefined behavior is why.

Comment: Undefined behavior. `x` may have any value, including 0.

Comment: You should compile with `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: The last printf is indented incorrectly

Answer (score 1):

There is no default value in C. If a variable is uninitialized, it will have a random value. In your case it seems to be 0 but it could be anything.

Comment: Not _random_ but _indeterminate_. And it's only true for local automatic variables. Global and static variables are automatically 0 initialized.

Comment: To be even more specific, it's *whatever was on the stack at that point* which is dependent on your program flow, compiler optimisations, and whichever program  used this memory segment before you (including your own dynamic linker)

Comment: @Adalcar Not necessarily, but likely. A C compiler is allowed to initialize variables to 0 (or another value) if it wants to.

Comment: It's far worse than "random". The compiler is essentially free to pickup *any* value whenever `x` is used. It could even eliminate all branches in the example or just select a cheapest one, as it would produce the best code.

Comment: @tstanisl since x is declared, it must be allocated somewhere on the stack, and anytime it is used, it will refer to this location, no? it's not THAT random

Comment: @Adalcar, No, it does not have to be allocated anywhere. C specification does not even mention the concept of "stack". The local variable exists only as a symbol in equations representing transformation between program states. The compiler can do everything with such an entity as long as side-effects of the program are the same. If case of UB, even "side-effects" constraint does not have to hold.

Comment: @Adalcar, See [uninitialized](https://godbolt.org/z/Ys6T4c)